# Unable to copy or move a file using python shutil

Tags: python, shutil

```
import shutil
import os

source = os.listdir("report")
destination = "archieved"

for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".json"):
        shutil.copy(files, destination)
```

I have the file named, '`a.json`' inside the report folder `report/a.json`; however, the file is not moved/copied to the target folder

**Console Error:**

```
*** FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.json'
```

[image]

Comment: If "reports" is the path to the directory, the name of the file ought to be "reports/a.json" when given to `shutil.copy`.

Comment: @Amdt actually, the JSON file used to be created dynamically

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but if there is a file "a.json" in the same directory as "reports", and a file "reports/a.json", your operation will access the former one, not the latter. Usually, the former one doesn't exist, which is what the program is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns filenames and not paths. You need to construct the paths from the filenames before calling `shutil.copy()`.

```
import shutil
import os

source_directory_path = "report"
destination_directory_path = "archived"

for source_filename in os.listdir(source_directory_path):
    if source_filename.endswith(".json"):
        # construct path from filename
        source_file_path = os.path.join(source_directory_path, source_filename)

        shutil.copy(source_file_path, destination_directory_path)
```

Comment: yes, this solved my issue; and I agree with the statement you've mentioned; thanks Pierre